# How to combine future_promise with memoise in R plumber

Tags: r, plumber, r-future, memoise, r-promises

I am making an API with R package `plumber`. Some endpoints in this API would benefit from memoization, so I also use the `memoise` package. Combining both is pretty straight-forward, as demonstrated in [this blog post](https://xiaolianglin.com/2018/12/05/Use-memoise-to-speed-up-your-R-plumber-API/). I'll build up on this post's example for my reprex.

```
# test.R
library(memoise)

# Define function ---------------------------------------------------------
add <- function(a, b) {
    a + b
}

# Memoisize function ------------------------------------------------------
add_mem <- memoise(add)

# Define API --------------------------------------------------------------
#* Return the sum of two numbers
#* @param a The first number to add
#* @param b The second number to add
#* @get /add
function(a, b) {
    add(as.numeric(a), as.numeric(b))
}

#* Return the sum of two numbers, use memoise cached results when applicable
#* @param a The first number to add
#* @param b The second number to add
#* @get /addWithMemoise
function(a, b) {
    add_mem(as.numeric(a), as.numeric(b))
}
```

```
# R console 1
plumber::plumb(file="test.R")$run(port=50000)
#Running plumber API at http://127.0.0.1:50000
#Running swagger Docs at http://127.0.0.1:50000/__docs__/
```

```
# R console 2
httr::GET("http://localhost:50000/add?a=1&b=1") %>% content()
#[[1]]
#[1] 2
httr::GET("http://localhost:50000/addWithMemoise?a=1&b=1") %>% content()
#[[1]]
#[1] 2
```

---

So now, I'd like to give my API the ability to handle concurrent calls. For this, I'll use the `promises` package, as demonstrated in [this blog post](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/future_promise.html). Combining `plumber` with `promises` is pretty straight-forward too:

```
# Added in test.R
library(promises)
#* Return the sum of two numbers, use promises
#* @param a The first number to add
#* @param b The second number to add
#* @get /addWithPromise
function(a, b) {
    future_promise({
        add(as.numeric(a), as.numeric(b))
    })
}
```

I restart the API, and then I can call this new endpoint:

```
# R console 2
httr::GET("http://localhost:50000/addWithPromise?a=1&b=1") %>% content()
#[[1]]
#[1] 2
```

---

Now I want to add an endpoint that mixes everything (`plumber`, `memoise` and `promises`).

```
# Added in test.R

#* Return the sum of two numbers, use promises and memoise cached results when applicable
#* @param a The first number to add
#* @param b The second number to add
#* @get /addWithPromiseMemoise
function(a, b) {
    future_promise({
        add_mem(as.numeric(a), as.numeric(b))
    })
}
```

I restart the API, then call it:

```
# R console 2
httr::GET("http://localhost:50000/addWithPromiseMemoise?a=1&b=1") %>% content()
#$error
#[1] "500 - Internal server error"
#
#$message
#[1] "Error in add_mem(as.numeric(a), as.numeric(b)): attempt to apply non-function\n"
```

```
# R console 1
#Unhandled promise error: attempt to apply non-function
#<simpleError in add_mem(as.numeric(a), as.numeric(b)): attempt to apply non-function>
```

---

I tried to mingle with `future_promise`'s `envir` argument, with no success.
I also tried this:

```
# Added in test.R

#* Return the sum of two numbers, use promises and memoise cached results when applicable
#* @param a The first number to add
#* @param b The second number to add
#* @get /addWithPromiseMemoiseTest
function(a, b) {
    print(names(environment(add_mem)))
    e <- environment(add_mem)
    future_promise({
        Sys.sleep(10)
        print(add_mem)
        print(class(add_mem))
        print(names(environment(add_mem)))
        environment(add_mem) <- e
        print(names(environment(add_mem)))
        add_mem(as.numeric(a), as.numeric(b))
    })
}
```

I restart the API, then call it:

```
# R console 2
httr::GET("http://localhost:50000/addWithPromiseMemoise?a=1&b=1") %>% content()
#[[1]]
#[1] 2
```

```
# R console 1
#[1] "_omit_args"    "_hash"         "_additional"   "_default_args" "_f_hash"       "_cache"        "_f"           
#Memoised Function:
#NULL
#[1] "memoised" "function"
# [1] "...future.startTime"    "...future.oldOptions"   "a"                      "b"                      "setdiff"                "...future.rng"          "e"                      "...future.frame"       
# [9] "...future.conditions"   "...future.mc.cores.old" "...future.stdout"       "add_mem"               
#[1] "_omit_args"    "_hash"         "_additional"   "_default_args" "_f_hash"       "_cache"        "_f"
```

It returns the right result, and the `future_promise` part works as expected (that I can see after adding a 10s `Sys.sleep` within the endpoint's `future_promise` call, then calling another `future_promise` endpoint from another R session), but the `memoise` part doesn't seem to work (that I can see after adding a 10s `Sys.sleep` within the `add` function, calling the last endpoint twice doesn't make it faster).

**EDIT:** this solution seems to work if I combine it with filesystem memoization:

```
# Changed in test.R

# Memoisize function ------------------------------------------------------
cache_fs <- cache_filesystem(".")
add_mem <- memoise(add, cache=cache_fs)
```

But it really doesn't look like a clean solution.

---

So as this is a long post, I'll state my question clearly in case I lost you:
**Is there a clean way to combine `memoise::memoise` and `promises::future_promise` within a `plumber` endpoint?**